# How can I safely use JSON.parse on a string object that might be a simple string or a string object?

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

I need to be able to parse a string in an object format or in a plain string format. what is the safest way to do this?

I tried JSON.parse(data) but it does not work in case that data is a plain string.

---

### EDIT - The chosen solution

Thanks to you, this is how I solved the problem:

```
try {
    dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
} catch (err) {
    if (typeof data === "object") {
        dataObj = data;
    } else {
        dataObj = {};
    }
}
```

Comment: If `data` can be an object, why don't you test that *before* you are trying to parse it? That would make more sense. Also, if it can be an object, why don't you mention that in your question? You said the value would be a string.

Comment: After I wrote the question I found more edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use try catch:

```
var result;
try {
   result = JSON.parse(data);
} catch (err) {
   if (typeof data == 'string') result = data;
   else console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the question now become how to distinguish between an error resulting from invalid JSON and from the "plain string"? (the first is unexpected but the second is expected) Or do you assume that if data contains the JSON, it will always be valid?

Comment: fixed: if (typeof data == 'string') result = data; else console.error(err);

Comment: Uhm, why would you expect `data` to be anything else but a string? Are you confusing JSON with JavaScript objects?

Comment: Agree with @FelixKling, the check needs to be safe for all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Create yourself a helper function and use that.

```
function parseValue(value) {
    try
    {
        return JSON.parse(value);
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        // JSON format was invalid
        // handle errors is you need to
    }

    return value;
}
```

If you're brave enough you can also extend String.prototype so calling it would become really straight forward.

```
String.prototype.parseJSON = String.prototype.parseJSON || function() {
    try
    {
        return JSON.parse(this);
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        // JSON format was invalid
        // handle errors is you need to
    }

    return this;
};
```

And then you'd simply call it this way:

```
// string in a variable
var s = "Some non-JSON string";
s.parseJSON();
// string literal
'{"b":true,"n":1}'.parseJSON();
```

Comment: Just to point out the "issue" with this approach (which does not mean this is a bad solution!): as already said `try/catch` handles every error, but there are actually two error cases we might want to distinguish: 1) the input is malformed JSON. This is an unexpected error in which case the JSON generation should probably be fixed. 2) the input is the plain string. This is expected, so the program should continue to run. To be fair though, if the JSON is generated using native functions, then case 1 is rather unlikely. Under this assumption, `try/catch` is the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JSON will always have the same format, you could also check whether the string starts with a `{"` (or just `{`), and only then parse it with `JSON.parse`.

It really depends of the possible input though.

Comment: That's quite ok, but you'll end up changing your code while `try/catch` covers them all... What do I mean? JSON object can start with `{` as well as with `[`. But these are just the ones from the top of my head. There could be other beginnings of JSON strings. So to make your code more bullet proof to cover whatever strings I think `try/catch` is a better way of doing this.

Comment: @Robert: It all depends on the context and possible input. The disadvantage with try...catch is that your missing the cases where the JSON is really broken, so is that really more bullet proof?. Btw,  `[` indicates an array, not an object. Based on their statement I assume it will always be an object if it's JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling: So where do you handle invalid JSON like `{{ this is worth nothing }}` in your code? `try/catch` would work in this situation, while your `if/else` would *think* it's JSON and you'd get an error while parsing it.

Comment: @Robert: I would want it to throw an error so that I know about it. If you silently catch it, it's more likely you don't know there is an issue.

Comment: but in browsers thrown errors don't display to user, you as a developer have to **handle them** and provide human-readable error info to your users. What this actually means? That you'd end up with a `try/catch` block as well. So why bother having `if/else` if you can cover everything with `try/catch` where you handle errors?

Comment: @Robert: I assumed that it would be a bug if the JSON is malformed and the developer has to fix whatever generates the JSON.