# how to solved json.parse when data is empty in ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I following this code to show my data in table, but this code error when data empty, "error JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1". please.. help me how can I solved this problem, and I want to make alert when json data is empty

```
$('#pilih').click(function(){
        const unit = document.getElementById('unit').value;
        const nosam = document.getElementById('nosam').value;
$.ajax({
            url: 'get/penjualan_data.php',
            data: {'unit': unit, 'nosam': nosam},
            cache: false,
        }).then(function(data){
            const json = data;
            obj = JSON.parse(json);
            
    var $table = $('#tampilkan tbody');
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    const a = i+1;
            var $row = 
                $("<tr>" +
        "<td>"+ a +"</td>" +
        "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>" +
                  "<td class='id'>"+ obj[i].nosam +"/"+ obj[i].gol +"</td>" +
        "<td>"+ obj[i].unit +"</td>" +
                  "<td class='nama'>"+ obj[i].nama +"</td>" +
        "<td>"+ obj[i].alamat +"</td>" +
                  "<td>"+ blnIndo(parseInt(obj[i].bulan)) +" "+ obj[i].tahun +"</td>" +
        "<td>"+  +"</td>" +
                  "<td style='text-align: right;' class='rp'>"+ titikAngka(obj[i].rupiah) +"</td>" +
                  "</tr>");
      
             $row.data(obj.nosam);
             $row.data(obj.nama);
             $row.data(obj.rupiah);
             $table.append($row);
   });
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I safely use JSON.parse on a string object that might be a simple string or a string object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501608/how-can-i-safely-use-json-parse-on-a-string-object-that-might-be-a-simple-string)

Comment: What's the value of `json` when you cannot parse it?

Answer (score 1):

As the first attempt, you can simply check your json data is empty.

```
if (json)
  obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

If your code can still get inputs with invalid json, use try-catch.

```
try {
 obj = JSON.parse(json);
}
catch(e) {
   console.log(e)
}
```

Comment: thank you, I try.. i hope this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your php script `penjualan_data.php` outputs `{}` if there is no data to display. Your error is that you're not receiving a proper JSON object in your response.

So even if `$data="";`
Still finish with `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: thats the problem, so.. how can I resolve that problem, i want to when data in penjualan_data is empty show alert no data found in search

Comment: Just updated my response - not sure if that's what you were asking...

Answer (score 0):

Display an alert, or empty table or an alternative layout, if no data is returned by the request.

```
 if(!data) { alert('sorry, no data was retrieved'); return; }
```